# gem install -s (specify source) not working as expected

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Firstly I will say that I'm using an old version of ruby (2.1.5), and this is unavoidable due to a legacy application.

What I am trying to achieve is the use source `https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies`, instead of source `https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies` when installing a gem via the cli.

I try to specify the source in the command by running:

`gem install bundler -s https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies -v '~>1.14' -V`

But the output suggests it still using `https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies`. I don't understand why this is, when I am explicitly stating the source in the command:

```
gem install bundler -s https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies -v '~>1.14'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 (https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bundler)
```

Also, when I run `gem sources`, I see:

`https://rubygems.org/`

So my question is, is there any other way to override the source the install command uses, or is there a reason why `-s`is not working as advertised?